# Area of triangle $OAB$

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

Question is :

Consider a circle of unit radius centered at $O$ in the plane. let $AB$ be a chord which makes an angle $\theta$ with the tangent to the circle at $A$ .find the area of triangle $OAB$

What all i could do was is just draw the picture and even in that i am not sure if he mean angle $BAP=\theta$ or $BAQ=\theta$. I am assuming for some time that $BAQ=\theta$
[image]

Now, I would have some hope if angle $OAB$ can be calculated from given data in terms of theta then i would use the area formula as

$\text{Area of triangle $OAB= \frac{1}{2}.OA.OB.\sin (\angle AOB)$}$ and as $OA=OB=1$ we would then get

Area of triangle $OAB=\frac{1}{2}.\sin (\angle AOB)$

But i am not sure how to relate $\theta$ with $\angle AOB$.

I am not even sure if there is any way to relate this.

I would be thankful if some one can help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: $$OA\perp PQ,$$ right?

Comment: The tangent is perpendicular to the radius.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee : Oh... how could i miss that... thank you.

Comment: @Lucian : Yes Yes... do not know how could i miss that... Thank you.. :)

Comment: Hmm...this question teaches me that intelligent people could sometimes also fail on simple questions :)

Comment: @Sawarnik : Intelligent? Whom are you referring to :P

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik You :p

Comment: @Sawarnik : Thank you :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle $(\angle BAQ)$ is a tangent (chord) angle.

[Theorem](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/geometry/circle/angle-tangent-and-chord.php) An Angle formed by a chord and a tangent that intersect on a circle is half the measure of the intercepted arc. 
So $$\theta=\frac{1}{2} m \overset{\frown}{(AB)}$$ 
from there  $(\angle AOB)=2\theta$

Comment: I am sorry, I could not understand...

Comment: Did you see theorem? In your case the angle $(\angle BAQ)$ is formed by a chord ($|AB|$) and a tangent ($|PQ|$) that intersect on a circle. So the measure of $\overset{\frown}{(AB)}$ is $2\theta$ and because of $(\angle AOB)$ is a center angle its measure is equal to $m \overset{\frown}{(AB)}$. Think  $m \overset{\frown}{(AB)}$ as small arc on the circle.

Comment: OK.. OK.. now i got it.. SO, area of triangle $OAB$ is $\frac{1}{2}. \sin (\angle AOB)=\frac{1}{2}. \sin (2\theta)=\frac{1}{2}. 2 sin(\theta) \cos(\theta)= sin(\theta) \cos(\theta)$.. Thank you so much for your support...

Comment: Yes, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Isosceles triangles have equal legs opposite equal base angles. 
Tangents to a circle at a point intersect at right angles to the radius at that point. 
It follows that the base angles are equal and complementary to $\theta$.

Area of a triangle = $\frac{1}{2}Base\cdot Height$

Suppose $\alpha + \theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\alpha$ is the measure of the base angle if this Isosceles triangle.

Area = $\frac{1}{2}(r\sin{\alpha})(2r\cos{\alpha})$

$r=1$ and the product $(\sin{\alpha}\cos{\alpha}) =(\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta})$ holds for complementary angles.